# Can't access the Fragment View's LifecycleOwner when getView() is null

Tags: java, android-studio, nullpointerexception, location, android-lifecycle

LifecycleOwner throws a null pointer exception inside the Search fragment in the `doSearch()` function.

I am trying to get location every 10 sec on my fragment class using the following code which is inside the `onCreateView`

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduleTaskExecutor= Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);
        // This schedule a task to run every 10 seconds:
        scheduleTaskExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            if(v.getContext() != null){
                try {
                    // code executes every 10 seconds.
                    searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
                    getLocation();
                    Log.d("TIMER", String.valueOf(scheduleTaskExecutor));

                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This works fine until I leave the fragment and the app will crash after it hits that 10 sec mark with a null pointer exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.dentdevils, PID: 16251
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't access the Fragment View's LifecycleOwner when getView() is null i.e., before onCreateView() or after onDestroyView()
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getViewLifecycleOwner(Fragment.java:361)
        at com.example.dentdevils.ui.fragments.FindCustomerFragment.doSearch(FindCustomerFragment.java:208)
        at com.example.dentdevils.ui.fragments.FindCustomerFragment.lambda$getLocation$5$FindCustomerFragment(FindCustomerFragment.java:171)
        at com.example.dentdevils.ui.fragments.-$$Lambda$FindCustomerFragment$elA84_sSqb0iRS3BrSq9azoX3zA.onSuccess(Unknown Source:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@17.2.0:4)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

search and location functions

```
  private void getLocation() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(requireContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            AppActivity a = (AppActivity) getActivity();
            LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(requireContext()).requestLocationUpdates(Objects.requireNonNull(a).mLocationRequest, null);
            fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(location -> {
                        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                        if (location != null) {
                            // Logic to handle location object
                            searchRequest.setLatitude(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()));
                            searchRequest.setLongitude(String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
                            userLocation = location;
                            Log.d("lat", searchRequest.getLatitude());
                            Log.d("long", searchRequest.getLongitude());
                            doSearch();
                        } else {
                            Log.d("Location", "Location is null");
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        Log.d("ERROR", "Failed");
                        if (searchRequest != null && searchRequest.getTerm() != null) {
                            doSearch();
                        }
                    })
            ;
        } else {
            // You can directly ask for the permission.
            // The registered ActivityResultCallback gets the result of this request.
            requestPermissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
    private void doSearch() {
        View view = requireActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) requireActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }

        Log.d("NOTICE", "searching");
        
        int rows = tableLayout.getChildCount();
        if (rows > 0) {
            tableLayout.removeViews(0, rows);
        }
        
        AppActivity a = (AppActivity) getActivity();

        CustomerRepository customerRepository = new CustomerRepository(Objects.requireNonNull(a).getApplication());
        customerRepository.search(searchRequest).observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), customers -> {
                Log.d("Found", String.valueOf(customers.size()));
                if (customers.size() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No results found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    TableRow[] tableRows = new TableRow[customers.size()];
                    // calculate distance of each customer from user
                    for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
                        Customer customer = customers.get(i);
                        try {
                            Location customerLocation = new Location("customer");
                            customerLocation.setLatitude(Double.parseDouble(customer.getLatitude()));
                            customerLocation.setLongitude(Double.parseDouble(customer.getLongitude()));
                            customer.setDistance(userLocation.distanceTo(customerLocation)*0.000621371f); // convert metres to miles
                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            customer.setDistance(0);
                        }
                    }
                    // sort by distance ascending
                    customers.sort((c,d) -> Float.compare(c.getDistance(), d.getDistance()));
                    for (int i = 0; i < customers.size(); i++) {
                        tableRows[i] = new TableRow(getContext());
                        tableRows[i].setId(i + 1);
                        tableRows[i].setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        ));
                        tableRows[i].setPadding(0, 20, 80, 20);
                        tableRows[i].setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
                        tableRows[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_outline);

                        TextView customerText = new TextView(getContext());
                        customerText.setId(i + 111);
                        customerText.setText(customers.get(i).getName());
                        customerText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        customerText.setPadding(14, 5, 5, 5);
                        customerText.setTextSize(16);
                        customerText.setMaxLines(3);
                        customerText.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                        customerText.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                        customerText.setWidth(200);

                        TextView text2 = new TextView(getContext());
                        text2.setId(i + 1111);
                        text2.setText(customers.get(i).getTown());
                        text2.setEms(4);
                        text2.setMaxLines(1);
                        text2.setTextSize(16);
                        text2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        text2.setTextAlignment(TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                        text2.setPadding(40, 5, 5, 5);

                        TextView text3 = new TextView(getContext());
                        text3.setId(i + 11111);
                        text3.setText(customers.get(i).getType());
                        text3.setEms(4);
                        text3.setMaxLines(1);
                        text3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        text3.setTextAlignment(TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                        text3.setTextSize(16);
                        text3.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

                        TextView text4 = new TextView(getContext());
                        text4.setId(i + 111111);
                        text4.setText(String.valueOf(customers.get(i).getDistance()));
                        text4.setEms(6);
                        text4.setMaxLines(2);
                        text4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                        text4.setTextAlignment(TextView.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
                        text4.setTextSize(16);
                        text4.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

                        tableRows[i].addView(customerText);
                        tableRows[i].addView(text2);
                        tableRows[i].addView(text3);
                        tableRows[i].addView(text4);
                        tableLayout.addView(tableRows[i], new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                                TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                        ));

                        tableRows[i].setClickable(true);
                        String customerId = customers.get(i).getUuid().toString();
                        tableRows[i].setOnClickListener(view1 -> {
                            TableRow tr = (TableRow) view1;
                            TextView s = (TextView) tr.getChildAt(0);
                            String r = s.getText().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), r, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                            Fragment addAppointmentWithExistingCustomerActivity = new AddAppointmentWithExistingCustomerFragment();
                            FragmentTransaction transaction = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                            Bundle addBundle = new Bundle();
                            addBundle.putString(CUSTOMER_ID, customerId);
                            addAppointmentWithExistingCustomerActivity.setArguments(addBundle);

                            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
                            // and add the transaction to the back stack if needed
                            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, addAppointmentWithExistingCustomerActivity);
                            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                            // Commit the transaction
                            transaction.commit();
                        });
                    }
                }
        });
    }
```